# How does the lastpass icon determine when to appear on a form input?

Tags: autofill, lastpass

The lastpass autofill icon appears on certain form fields, and on my site it has appeared unexpectedly on an input, with `autocomplete="off"`, with no `id` and a `name` of `CatName_autocomplete`.

I understand I can add an attribute to disable it, but unless I do this for everything in my site, plus any other rival password managers, it could potentially crop up elsewhere. It interferes with my own custom javascript autocomplete functionality that I have on the control because it doesn't trigger the correct events to work properly.

Is there a way to find out the specific underlying logic it uses to decide whether to appear in an input? This would allow me to check I don't accidentally write misleading inputs that trigger it, or that I can know to put the attribute to disable it onto those I know would trigger.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I'm afraid not, as I recall, I put an attribute in to remove it, but I could only apply that to the fields that users reported to me, and we only had one guy that used the plugin. `Autocomplete="off"` doesn't work either in Chrome, they decided they know better than the developer and it only works if you put a random string in (I used a guid), e.g. `Autocomplete="wibble12345"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's far more complicated than this, but in case it helps anyone: I disabled the icon in many fields on my page just by removing 'id' from the name attribute of the FIRST input element.

```
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Schedule ID"
         name="scheduleId" [(ngModel)]="scheduleId" aria-label="Schedule ID"/>
```

triggers icons on the page, not just on this form.

```
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Schedule ID"
         name="schedule" [(ngModel)]="scheduleId" aria-label="Schedule ID"/>
```

does not.